# Powershell script for listing specific expiring accounts

Tags: powershell, active-directory, user-accounts

I am a bit of a powershell novice so any help is greatly appreciated. I am using the following script to get and export a list of AD accounts that are expiring, that match the specific description item. I have not been able to get it to successfully include the expiration date. This is the script as it currently works.

```
   $users = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 10000 -SearchRoot 'company.com/employees' -IncludedProperties "description" | where {$_.description -like "non-company*" }
@(foreach($user in $users)
{
$user | Select-Object DisplayName,LogonName,description

}) |  export-Csv "C:\Users\svcacct\Documents\Steve Test Scripts\test.csv" -noType
```

I have tried adding `-filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq  $False}` but it just fails.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False) -and (Description -like "non-company*")} -SearchBase "OU=employees,DC=Company,DC=com" -Properties Description,DisplayName,sAMAccountName

@(ForEach($user In $users){
    $user | Select-Object DisplayName,sAMAccountName,Description
}) | Export-Csv "C:\Users\svcacct\Documents\Steve Test Scripts\test.csv" -noType
```